# LINQ Contains Case Insensitive

Tags: c#, linq

This code is case sensitive, how to make it case insensitive?

```
public IQueryable<FACILITY_ITEM> GetFacilityItemRootByDescription(string description)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.FACILITY_ITEM.Where(fi => fi.DESCRIPTION.Contains(description));
}
```

Comment: Sjoerd's answers is correct but... 
I want to get search results for names with a turkish İ (for example) when writing an i and vice versa. In this case ToLower seems to be the correct way to go. Please correct me if i'm wrong.
About turkish İ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Comment: @HeNrik - As discussed in Turkey Test link in JYelton's comment under accepted answer, when run with Turkish culture, those two i's will be different - so you won't find names with the other i. You want ToLowerInvariant. See discussion under various answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225808/string-tolower-and-string-tolowerinvariant).

Comment: this is an old question, but it is worth to note that in the current version EF core 2.0 ToLower() works as follows  person.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(myParam.Name.ToLower()));  I am using this in a Linq query against a Postgres DB. I do not have case insensitivty on the column collation in the DB and I checked that without ToLower() the match is clearly case sensitive.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that most answers seem to think that this is LINQ to objects. Only a few are aware of the database collation as the determining factor. `IQueryable` and `ObjectContext` should be a clear indication that this is about a LINQ-to-entities query.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Assuming we're working with strings here, here's another "elegant" solution using `IndexOf()`.

```
public IQueryable<FACILITY_ITEM> GetFacilityItemRootByDescription(string description)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.FACILITY_ITEM
        .Where(fi => fi.DESCRIPTION
                       .IndexOf(description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Nice. For my own purposes though, this doesn't work for LINQ to Entities. Nice solution for LINQ to Objects though.

Comment: IndexOf may cause trouble if one item is substring in other item,e.g `{"ora","orange","ora2"}`

Answer (score 266):

```
fi => fi.DESCRIPTION.ToLower().Contains(description.ToLower())
```

Comment: there might be a more elegant solution, but this is logical and works anyhow. I will look for the elegant solution later

Comment: As [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) commented on a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/444813/161052), this method won't pass the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: No, but databases work off of character sets and collation. If you're trying to push off work to the database, you have to make some assumptions about character set and collation, right?

Comment: Contains should  be using `IEqualityComparer<string>` attribute to handle how the comparison will work. Use ToLower and ToUpper to check equality is a bad idea. Try: `.Contains(description, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` for example

Comment: The comment by @Dorival should be the answer.

Comment: The comment from @Dorival doesnt work, as it gives this errormessage: `Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: There are many ways to do that, the use of Equality is always recommended. Another way, perhaps even faster is to use the `IndexOf` method as: `.Where(fi =>  fi.DESCRIPTION.IndexOf(description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));`. A solution that Jeff Mercado suggested as an answer in this page.

Comment: `Contains` with `StringComparer` doesn't receive string as parameter, so it will be build-error. `IndexOf` on `Queryable` probably can't be translated into SQL. Personally I found this answer to be totally valid as we speak about LINQ to database.

Comment: If you are going to use  fi => fi.DESCRIPTION.ToLower().Contains(description.ToLower())  you should first store the lowercase value in a variable (var desc = description.ToLower()) so you don't repeat the ToLower() for each item in your recordset.

Comment: A very elegant solution. Usually, case-sensitive issue only appears on poorly designed programs, and this is a good patch for such systems. Personally, I should have written a code to format every string before it goes to the database, but didn't bother with that. So I need this.

Answer (score 140):

If the LINQ query is executed in database context, a call to `Contains()` is mapped to the `LIKE` operator:

`.Where(a => a.Field.Contains("hello"))`
 becomes `Field LIKE '%hello%'`. The `LIKE` operator is case insensitive by default, but that can be changed by [changing the collation of the column](https://clicdatacoder.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/using-case-sensitive-comparisons-in-linq-to-entity/comment-page-1/).

If the LINQ query is executed in .NET context, you can use [IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425), but that method is not supported in LINQ to SQL.

LINQ to SQL [does not support methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx) that take a CultureInfo as parameter, probably because it can not guarantee that the SQL server handles cultures the same as .NET. This is not completely true, because it *does* support `StartsWith(string, StringComparison)`.

However, it does not seem to support a method which evaluates to `LIKE` in LINQ to SQL, and to a case insensitive comparison in .NET, making it impossible to do case insensitive Contains() in a consistent way.

Comment: Just FYI EF 4.3 does not support StartsWith. I get: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean StartsWith(System.String, System.StringComparison)'

Comment: StartWith converts to LIKE 'hello%' ?

Comment: clicdata link is dead.

Comment: great effort for digging into generated SQL and db behavior for LIKE clause

Comment: So what is ones options when using EF, In one context i need to do case `insensitive` search, and in the other I need it to be `case sensitive`. Do I just have to take the performance knock and use 'toLower()'?

Comment: I used toLower(), and then I got an error  like "couldn't be translated"

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer here does not mention a fact that if you have a null string ToLower() will throw an exception. The safer way would be to do:

```
fi => (fi.DESCRIPTION ?? string.Empty).ToLower().Contains((description ?? string.Empty).ToLower())
```

Comment: You can't gen an exception on a query translated to SQL

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy How is that even relevant to this problem? If fi.DESCRIPTION is null or description is null you're getting a C# null reference exception. It doesn't matter what the LINQ query converts to on the SQL side. Here's the proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5pZ1dY

Comment: Because this query will fail translation to SQL because it doesn't support null coaleshing operator. And you probably quering database instead of loading out all the entries to use null coaleshing on client side. So if you use it - it's ok on client side but fail on DB, otherwise you're ok with DB and you don't care about nullref on client side because it won't happen becasue C# doesn't execute this query and doesn't actually read null objects.

Comment: This answer helped me solve a problem I was getting on LINQ to Entities where I was doing .IndexOf and .Contains on an IEnumerable where the string value coming from the database was null. I wasn't getting the error until the result was enumerated and then I got an error message that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I couldn't figure out why it was occurring until I saw this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Using C# 6.0 (which allows expression bodied functions and null propagation), for LINQ to Objects, it can be done in a single line like this (also checking for null):

```
public static bool ContainsInsensitive(this string str, string value) => str?.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Comment: It's not working because ContainsInsensitive is not a store command

Comment: @Sven - yes, it works only for LINQ to Objects. I have fixed my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

IndexOf works best in this case

```
return this
   .ObjectContext
   .FACILITY_ITEM
   .Where(fi => fi.DESCRIPTION.IndexOf(description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)>=0);
```

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, this doesn't need to be difficult. It may seem that on the onset, but it's not. Here's a simple linq query in C# that does exactly as requested.

In my example, I'm working against a list of persons that have one property called FirstName.

```
var results = ClientsRepository().Where(c => c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList();
```

This will search the database on lower case search but return full case results.

Comment: as said in another answer, this fails if `searchText` is null or if any of the `c.FirstName` are null.

Comment: You will just have to perform extra handling on this. First if the searchText is null, then you wrap this in an if statement. Second, perform a null check on c.FirstName, such as c=> c.FirstName != null && c.FirstName.ToLower().... The first part of the and condition should stop it checking the second if the first name is null.

Answer (score 4):

You can use string.Compare

```
    lst.Where(x => string.Compare(x,"valueToCompare",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==0);
```

if you just want to check contains then use "Any"

```
  lst.Any(x => string.Compare(x,"valueToCompare",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==0)
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. The OP is asking about ‘Contains’ _within a string_ (i.e., one string contains another), not whether a collection of strings contains a single string.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool Contains(this string input, string findMe, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) ? false : input.IndexOf(findMe, comparisonType) > -1;
}
```

Comment: can we use custom extension methods in linq queries ? are you sure ?

Answer (score 1):

> [StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) just do the job for me:

```
.Where(fi => fi.DESCRIPTION.Contains(description, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **String.Equals** Method

```
public IQueryable<FACILITY_ITEM> GetFacilityItemRootByDescription(string description)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.FACILITY_ITEM
           .Where(fi => fi.DESCRIPTION
           .Equals(description, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```