# Case-insensitive LINQ (without toUpper or toLower)

Tags: c#, linq, case-insensitive

```
public Articles GetByName(string name, Categories category, Companies company)
{
    var query = from article in session.Linq<Articles>()
                where article.Name == name &&
                      article.Category == category &&
                      article.Company == company
                select article;
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

How to make the LINQ query case-insensitive? I can use `toLower()` or `toUpper()`, but I want to use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 125):

Use `String.Equals` with the appropriate parameters to make it case insensitive

```
mySource.Where(s => String.Equals(s, "Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: hmm now i get Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: left

Comment: Are you sure?  `String.Equals` should be able to accept null as a parameter.

Comment: if i use toUpper then i get Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index. works only the code i paste...

Comment: FirstOrDefault is probably returning null, which you might be using without first checking.  Break up your code a bit and make certain that String.Equals is what's failing, because, again, String.Equals should be able to accept null as a parameter

Comment: What kind of error? `FirstOrDefault()` returns null if the LINQ statement doesn't match any results.

Comment: It sounds like you have some other problem with your query.  You need to gather your code and ask a new question.

Comment: I've having the same problem as @senzacionale, consuming an IQueryable object generated by NHibernate. I wonder if it's an NHibernate problem?

Comment: Possibly.  NH's Linq parser might be confused by String.Equals?  Just to be sure, you're using String.Equals(s1, s2) and not str.Equals(str2), right?

Comment: Whats about [string-comparison exception EF firstordefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950018/string-comparison-exception-within-entity-framework-firstordefault) ?

Answer (score 62):

Instead of `==` use the `.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` method.

```
var query = from article in session.Linq<Articles>()
            where article.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                  article.Category.Equals(category) &&
                  article.Company.Equals(company)
            select article;

return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please take care with String.Equals() and StringComparison in combination with LINQ. Depending on the database system the option could be ignored. E.g. SQLite or Oracle.

Answer (score 29):

If this is a LINQ to SQL query against a database with a case-insensitive collation, then it already is case-insensitive. Remember that LINQ to SQL isn't actually executing your == call; it's looking at it as an expression and converting it to an equality operator in SQL.

If it's LINQ to Objects, then you can use String.Equals as the other posters have pointed out.

Answer (score 9):

```
var query = from article in session.Linq<Articles>()
           where string.Equals(article.Name,name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                 string.Equals(article.Category,category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                 string.Equals(article.Company,company, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        select article;

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
```

It will also handle when Name,Category,Company is `null`

Comment: This particular solution isn't necessarily supported.  For example using Linq2SQL, on SQLServer2008:


`Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL.`


similarly:


`'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Comment: @mcdrewski I actually get `Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'` even when I'm _clearly_ providing the expected arguments.  Using EF4 I think, probably a bug.

Comment: @drzaus go with Edgar's answer using the Equals method off the property rather than static one from the type.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using C# 6.0 you can define a short extension method to be used when constructing LINQ statements:

```
public static bool EqualsInsensitive(this string str, string value) => string.Equals(str, value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Usage:

```
query.Where(item => item.StringProperty.EqualsInsensitive(someStringValue));
```

For C# less than 6.0 it will look like this:

```
public static bool EqualsInsensitive(this string str, string value) 
{
    return string.Equals(str, value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
String.Equals(article.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Huh - never used `OrdinalIgnoreCase` before - what's the difference between that and `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`?

Comment: @Adam Racks: RTFM ;) Basically, your solution takes into account comparison rules of the current culture, while mine does a simple byte by byte comparison after making both strings upper case. A google or SO search will bring up a lot of info on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
public Articles GetByName(string name, Categories category, Companies company)
        {
    var query = from article in session.Linq<Articles>()
                            where string.Equals(article.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)  == name &&
                                string.Equals(article.Category, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase == category &&
                                string.Equals(article.Company, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase == company
                            select article;

                return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string.Equals(name, article.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

when **you are sure** that your database supports it.

E.g. SQLite with a collate of `NOCASE` will ignore the option.
Oracle uses session settings `NLS_COMP`, `NLS_SORT` that will be taken.

Else use `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` when you have no culture issues.