# String Comparison exception within Entity Framework FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, entity-framework, string-comparison

I'm querying a table using Entity Framework. The first bit of code was what I wrote, the second bit was what ReSharper suggested I refactor it too. The first one gracefully returns null as it should if the key doesn't exist, but the second throws an exception.

This was attempted with 0-1 records in the table (all of the columns are marked as NOT NULL)

Code that works:

```
context.brandlink.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ManufacturerKey.ToLower() == manufacturerKey.ToLower());
```

and code that doesn't work:

```
context.brandlink.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.ManufacturerKey, manufacturerKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Exception thrown:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean
>   Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

So my question is: what is the difference between the two expressions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So my question is: what is the difference between the two expressions?

The diffence is that the later is using the CLR [String.Equals Method (String, String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not supported by EF according to [CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681(v=vs.110).aspx) while all the methods used in the former (`string.ToLower` and string equality operator) are supported.

In general you cannot control the string comparisons for EF queries from code because they are controlled by the database.

Comment: solution for ***OrdinalIgnoreCase*** in EF is use `ToLower()` ?