# Case insensitive Contains with Dynamic Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, contains

When using `Contains` with Dynamic Linq on Linq-to-objects, the search is case sensitive. I would like to be able to search case insensitive (like Linq-to-sql, cause SQL server does this by default).

Something like:

```
this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where(field + ".Contains(@0, true)", strValue);
```

where `true` means: `caseinsensitive = true`, like one of the extensions of `System.String.Contains` provides. Though i cannot use extensions to `System.String` with dynamic Linq by default.

Comment: It seems that 'this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where(field + "ToLower().Contains(@0, true)", strValue.ToLower());' works. I've made some changes to Dynamic.cs, so I don't know if it works by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: Not a duplicate because that's not about dynamic linq.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can you just .ToLower() both sides of the comparison?  Something like this:

```
this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where(field.ToLower().Contains(strValue.ToLower()));
```

Or did I misunderstand what you're looking for?

Comment: ToLower() isn't supported in Dynamic Linq

Comment: I'll be d*mned... I tried this and it worked, which yesterday obviously didnt work: this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where(field + "ToLower().Contains(@0, true)", strValue.ToLower());

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple. I know I've tried this yesterday, but probably made a typo or something. Well thx for your suggesting!

Comment: Likewise, `this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where(String.Format("{0}.ToLower().Contains(\"{1}\")", field, value.ToLower()))` will work.

Comment: Also, what should seem obvious but took me a while is to make sure that 'field' is a string and not some other type (complex object, int, etc)

Comment: Is the accepted answer actually correct or should @RolandDeschain's comment be added as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

When using "toLower", make sure you include the () "ToLower()"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use placeholders then your code should look like

```
this.someQuery = this.someQuery.Where("field" + ".ToLower().Contains(@0.ToLower())", strValue);
```