# Search and filter on datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm load gridview to form using below function

```
private DataClasses1DataContext db_cooperations = new DataClasses1DataContext();
private int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 20;
private int CurrentPageIndex = 1;

Func<IEnumerable<cooperations>, IEnumerable<cooperations>> ordering = t => t.OrderBy(i => i.name);

private void daftarKoperasi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData(CurrentPageIndex);
    dataGridProperty();
}

 private void GetData(int page)
{
    page = page - 1;
    db_cooperations.Log = Console.Out;  

    var query = (from c in ordering(db_cooperations.cooperations)
                select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city })
                .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage).ToList();


    dataGridView1.DataSource = query ;
}
```

Then I want to search the data based on **name** and at the same time filtering the **city**. Any clue what should I do further?

**UPDATE**

So I update my code as follow

```
private void GetData(int page)
{
    page = page - 1;
    db_cooperations.Log = Console.Out;  

    var query = (from c in ordering(db_cooperations.cooperations)
                select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city })
                .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage).ToList();


    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTxt.Text) == false)
    {
        query.Where(c => c.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower()));
    }

    if (cityCB.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
        query.Where(c => c.city.ToLower().Equals(cityCB.Text.ToLower()));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = query ;
}
```

But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter(search) the data based on *`name`* and at the same time filtering the *`city`* in *Linq to Sql*.

You have use `or` [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174986.aspx) of `SQL` which represent as `||` *or* `|` in C# and [.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) represents as `LIKE` of `SQL`. Here's a good example about filtering using `.Contains` [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)

```
        var query = (from c in ordering(db_cooperations.cooperations)
                     select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city })
                     .where(c => c.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower()) || 
                            c => c.city.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower()))
            .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage).ToList();
```

PS: It might be I will miss your question but you go like this,

```
.where(c => c.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower()) && 
                                c => c.city == cityCB.Text)
```

**EDIT:**

From your update,

```
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTxt.Text) == false)
    {
      query = query.Where(c => c.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
    }

    if (cityCB.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
       query =  query.Where(c => c.city.ToLower().Equals(cityCB.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: @l1th1um, i updated my answser, but.. have you tried my first answer?

Answer (score 1):

add a where clause to the linq statement.

BTW: all of your ordering, filtering & projections are done in memory. you are loading the entire record set into memory before applying any of this because you are using `IEnumerable<Corproations>` instead of `IQueryable<Corporations>`.

```
(from c in db_cooperations.cooperations 
where c.Name == name && c.City == city
order by c.Name)
.Skip(pagesize * page).Take(pagesize).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: for the ordering I could use this one : `ordering = t => t.OrderBy(i => i.nama);`. Then for searching, I try this : `ordering = t => t.Where(i=>i.name.Contains(searchTxt.Text));`. But it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

So I'm solve the problem as code below

```
var query = (from c in ordering(db_cooperations.cooperations)
                         select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city })
                         .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTxt.Text) == false && searchTxt.Text.Trim() != "Search....")
    {
        query = from c in query
        where c.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTxt.Text.ToLower())
        select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city })
    }

if (kotaCB.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        query = from c in query
                where c.kota.ToLower().Equals(kotaCB.Text.ToLower())
                select new { c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.email, c.city });
        }

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Thanks all for helping me @spajce, @Jason