# LINQ To Entities Contains Case In-Sensitive Searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

i am trying to query my resultset like this in linq to entities;

```
var categoriesList = _catRepo.GetAllCategories();


 filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("for"));
```

However, i don't get any result becuase the `CategoryName` is `For(Upper Case)` in the database. I have also checked the sql server collation and it is set to **_CI_AS**. I have no idea **how to use contains to filter case insensitive string?**
I want basically if someone type like;

```
 filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("for"));
```

OR

```
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.Contains("For"));
```

The result should be the same

Comment: Does this answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive

Comment: it doens't work for me

Comment: I think that normally works with the collation you say. Are you sure that `categoriesList` is a DB query and not an already queried in memory list (in which case your expression won't be translated to sql). Also, if you trace the db queries at that point, what SQL is being generated?

Comment: What type is `filteredCategories`? Can you show the variable declaration?

Comment: Hmm, theres a few suggestions in that link, so I'm not sure what you mean by by _it_ doesn't work for me..

Comment: it is already quried in memory

Comment: Does `GetAllCategores` return an IQueryable or an IEnumerable?

Comment: var categoriesList is a type of List<CategoryViewModel>

Comment: Right, so this is NOTHING to do with the DB. You're fetching all the entities back from the DB and you want to do an in-memory filter of them.

Comment: thanks to all of you for your precious time

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=>
 c.CategoryName.IndexOf("for", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Contains method works as shown below

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
   return this.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if working directly on EF objects. Can't translate `IndexOf()`

Comment: Doesn't Work with Entity Framework 5. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 7):

The previous `IndexOf` answer should work. Because you are loading all the entities from the database and then doing an in-memory (linq to objects) filter on it, you are not doing anything on the database at all.

This should also work (from the post I referenced)

```
filteredCategories = categoriesList.Where(c=> c.CategoryName.ToLower().Contains("for"));
```

Just an aside, if you have a lot of categories, then you might want to filter them on the database, rather than fetch all from the db and then filter them in memory..

Comment: Contains will call IndexOf anyways

Comment: @Shymep Yup I know, I was just offering this one up for completeness :)

Comment: This doesn't pass the Turkey Test http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html