# How to select items containing any word in a string using Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I've a table that contains details of Members.
The Name field will be having values like "John Antony", "Sarah Ann Mathew", "Josh John".

How do I select all members who are having names containing any of the words in "John, Ann, Mathew".

I've tried implementations like `db.members.Where(m=>names.Contains(m.Name));` but the issue is that I am trying to match any word in `m.Name`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make `names` a collection of strings `{"John", "Ann", "Mathew"}` and try `db.members.Where(m=>names.Any(n => m.Contains(n)));`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It works. Please post it as an answer. I shall accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make names a collection of strings, like this `{"John", "Ann", "Mathew"}`, you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
var res = db.members.Where(m=>names.Any(n => m.Name.Contains(n)));
```

Comment: just watch out for case sensitivity

Comment: @Miles Yes. found that issue `"John"` matches `"jonathan swift"` too. Is there any way to match the whole word or match case?

Comment: @LibinTK Here is [an answer about case sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3360808/335858). Exact matches are a little trickier - you may want to to use EF for fast pre-filtering, and then do additional filtering in memory with regex. Regex lets you add `\b` on both sides of a name for word boundaries - something you cannot do with EF's `Contains`.

Comment: @RalphLavelle Thanks!