# Concatenate IQueryable starting with Empty IQueryable in VB

Tags: vb.net, linq, concatenation, iqueryable

I am trying to concatenate multiple LINQ requests returns (all the returns are IQueryable).

My problem is that I need to start with an Empty IQueryable variable, but the ".Concat" method doesn't work with a variable that is "Nothing".

I was wondering if you had a way of doing this?

PS: You can use multiple "Where" requests as "AND" but not as "OR" (Seq.Where(Seq.Where())). I am trying to do the latter by concatenating multiple requests. Also, if I do an impossible request (A request returning no match), it works, but it is clearly not a good idea.

Comment: Definitely [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Use `PredicateBuilder` instead to get multiple `OR` conditions.

Comment: There is many ways to do "OR"s depending on what type of OR you need to do via `Aggregate`, `Intersects`, `Contains`, and `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I had to do my request once on the first item of the list, then remove the item. After that, I could simply do a for each (using "Contains" to query my database).

Still, this is not really an answer I think. It pretty much looks like a hack.

I did not find a way to to my query with linq.

I was querying my database using `Contains` and verifying if x was in the database. But I had to to this for a list of x.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. What I have done so far is use a LINQ query which returns no rows, and for some reason, that works fine. New lists (like Robert's answer) and `Enumerable.Empty<>` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var start=(new List<something>()).AsQueryable();
```

Although this will likely only work if your IQueryable is over the same source (in this case, objects).  I suggest trying to figure out a LINQ way of doing your "OR" properly, either through `Aggregate`, `Intersects`, `Contains`, `Any` or  `PredicateBuilder`.

Comment: I already use a "Contains" to query my database to test if x is in it. I would have to test for all x in a list of x, and for each of them I would have to test the contains. I have no idea how to do this with LINQ.

Comment: If you give some example data, inputs, and wanted output, I'm sure we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem. I found two options that could help you but have a drawback.

Instead of using `AsQueryable()` (suggested in other posts), try these *(sorry, just C# code, but I guess it may be useful anyway)*:

```
var query = new List<ServiceTicketCombinedHistory>().Take(0);
var query = Enumerable.Empty<ServiceTicketCombinedHistory>();
// Optionally:
var query = Enumerable.Empty<ServiceTicketCombinedHistory>().Take(0);
```

The problem in my case is that my query has a `Where(x => x.Field.Contains(value))`, and with these options, this comparison seems to be done on memory and is **case sensitive**. By using an empty LINQ query result (like you did), the comparison seems to be done in the **database** with a `LIKE` and is **case insensitive**. More info about this difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965710/2321042).

The LINQ query approach I used, instead of deleting the item, is to add a `Take(0)` to the whole query (you have to surround it with parenthesis). That results in the simplest execution plan for the SQL Server.