# How to user OrdinalIgnoreCase in linq EF query against contain?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

What is wrong with this code ?

```
var tags = "Tom;DC;Harry"
var tagArray = tags.Split(';');
var searchTags = dbContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Active && tagArray.Contains(t.TagLabel, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

This gives me the following error at runtime.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String],
>   System.String,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[System.String])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

But when I turn the code to:

```
var searchTags = dbContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Active && tagArray.Contains(t.TagLabel.ToLower())).ToList();
```

It works for me, but this way I have to convert all `tags` & `tagArray` to lower. 
Is there any way around to ignorecase in EF query ?

Comment: No other way. The query is translated to SQL and string collation is controlled by the database

Comment: read this answer this might enlighten you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11965710/4827151

Comment: @ivanStoev what this guy asking is how he can compare string without checking case.

Comment: @KaushikThanki I know what he's asking. The question is how to do that in LINQ to Entities. He found a way (using `ToLower`), so my comment was just confirming it's the only way.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Your answer is correct. Why did you comment instead of answering? :-)

Comment: @Nils Because most probably the question is a dupe, I'm just too lazy to search for it :)