# How to find column value by comparing another column value in LINQ where case does not any matter

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq

Here string productname2="xyz" but actually in database PRODUCTNAME is "XYZ" when I compare it return false,so I could not get productcode,here I want not only compare but also some value from this satetement.

```
orderdetail.PRODUCTCODE = context.PRODUCTs.Where(pro => pro.PRODUCTNAME==productname2)
                         .Select(code => code.PRODUCTCODE).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How about using ToLowerInvariant() on both sides of your comparison?

Comment: @wkl `ToLower` has internationalisation issues - always better to use the relevant override of `string.Equals(...)`

Comment: I don't believe that this is best solved in the query. Given that this is coming from the DB, it looks like you might better benefit from setting the correct (case-insensitive) collation on the column in the database. By converting case, you are discarding the benefit of any indexes you might have on the column.

Comment: @RowlandShaw You are right, I edited my comment to using ToLowerInvariant. I think that should do it.

Comment: @wkl IIRC, that will blow up when it gets translated to SQL.

Comment: could you please specify the data provider you are querying against? objects, sql, ...?

Comment: @Jehof Yah,I use entity frame work with Oracle

Comment: @ Andreas Niedermair it is Oracle

Comment: So, it's [tag:linq-to-entities]?

Answer (score 3):

You have to compare strings ignoring case :

```
orderdetail.PRODUCTCODE = context.PRODUCTs.Where(pro => pro.PRODUCTNAME.Equals(productname2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).Select(code => code.PRODUCTCODE).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use `string.Equals` instead of `instance.Equals`, as the former call is null-safe :) Additionally, I would also question if you need culture-aware comparison, or ordinal - the later one has better performance ... As always, depending on the data provider you querying against (some calls might not get translated to pure sql ...)

Comment: Will this translate to SQL?

Comment: .Select(code => code.PRODUCTCODE).DefaultIfEmpty().Max(); do not work properly this option,it show syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
.Where(pro => pro.PRODUCTNAME.Equals(productname2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

`OrdinalIgnoreCase` and `CultureIgnoreCase` just differs in the rules applied for comparison, where the former performs better with less rules than latter.

Comment: No syntax error but I have got the same result,I do not found the product code for case sensative

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
orderdetail.PRODUCTCODE = context.PRODUCTs.Where(pro => pro.PRODUCTNAME.ToLower().Contains(productname2.ToLower())).Select(code => code.PRODUCTCODE).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

from this link [LINQ Contains Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)