# Can't get case-insensitive searches on SQLite

Tags: c#, android, maui, sqlite-net

Using SQLite I'm trying to do a case-insensitive search on a string column, however it's only returning results when the case matches the column exactly.

The connection is setup as:

```
new SQLiteAsyncConnection(_dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache));
```

*I'm not using any pragma's to configure LIKE case sensitivity*

The table is defined as:

```
[Table($"{nameof(Customer)}s")]
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Collation("NOCASE")]
    public string? BusinessName { get; set; }
    [Collation("NOCASE")]
    public string? Suburb { get; set; }
    // ... etc.
}
```

(After adding the `Collation` attribute, I dropped and recreated the table).

There are multiple issues with this.

First, my data has about 9 customers in "BRUNSWICK HEADS" (all uppercase thanks to upstream data out of my control).

1. Using Linq

```
        var search = "BRUNSWICK";

        List<Customer> entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.BusinessName.Contains(search) ||
                    c.Suburb.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine1.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine2.Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();
```

This returns 9 results, but search term and columns are all uppercase.

2. Mixed case search-terms. These all return 0 results, indicating that the search is case-sensitive.

```
        search = "BrUNSWICK"; // note lower-case 'r'

        entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.BusinessName.Contains(search) ||
                    c.Suburb.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine1.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine2.Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();

        entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.Suburb.Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();

        search = "BrUNSWICK HeADS";

        entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.BusinessName.Contains(search) ||
                    c.Suburb.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine1.Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine2.Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();

        entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.Suburb.Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();
```

3. Perhaps it's just a problem with Linq queries... Let's try SQL expressions:

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Suburb = '?'";
        entities = await _conn.QueryAsync<Customer>(query, "BrUNSWICK HeADS");
```

returns 0 results! (It's a problem with the parameter, not `=` being case-sensitive)

4.

```
        query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Suburb LIKE '%?%'";
        entities = await _conn.QueryAsync<Customer>(query, "BRUNSWICK");
```

returns 0 results! (It's a problem with the parameter, not `LIKE` being case-sensitive)

5.

```
        query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Suburb = '?'";
        entities = await _conn.QueryAsync<Customer>(query, "BRUNSWICK HEADS");
```

An exact match returns no results...

6.

```
        query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Suburb = 'BRUNSWICK HEADS'";
        entities = await _conn.QueryAsync<Customer>(query);
```

Returns 9 results - so `=` is working, but parameters aren't?

7.

```
        query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Suburb LIKE '%BRUNSWICK%'";
        entities = await _conn.QueryAsync<Customer>(query);
```

Returns 9 results - so `LIKE` is working, but parameters aren't?

*The SQL string statements I can live without, so that's not a focus of this question.* The only way to get this working is the following:

```
        search = "BrUNSWICK HeADS".ToLower(); // actually from user input!
        entities = await _conn.Table<Customer>()
                .Where(c =>
                    c.BusinessName.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                    c.Suburb.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine1.ToLower().Contains(search) ||
                    c.AddressLine2.ToLower().Contains(search)
                ).ToListAsync();
```

This returns 9 results, but now we can't use column indexes.

Can someone please enlighten me?

There is no mention of COLLATE on [TwinCoders](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/) site (the SQLiteNetExtensions nuget package website)

There is a [unit test for sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/tests/SQLite.Tests/CollateTest.cs) which seems to indicate it's working.

Comment: Have you tried some of the approaches mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360772/linq-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: What's the database collation set to?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran that Q is 12+ years old, I'm not sure what database the OP or most of the commentors are referring to, but the libraries I mention probably weren't around then.

Comment: @Flydog57 I haven't set anything specific beyond what you see in the code I posted. The Android emulator is set to en-US.

Comment: @thinkOfaNumber LINQ itself is over 15 years old, you should try , just because the mentioned Q is 12+ years old does not negate the approaches.